# local on premise single database for desktop as well as web application

Tags: windows, web, client-server

I'm involved in a new project where my client is keen on having a local on premise database for their daily business transactions.The requirement is to build a desktop (windows based) application which will connect to the local database server. However in future they also want their customers to be able to view information contained in that local database. for example: view their profile,transactions etc.

Our first approach, was in suggesting them to opt for a web application altogether.But since web application would be dependent on the network speed and considering the critically of everyday data entry/updates, they are insisting on having a desktop application for their inhouse operations.

Is it possible to build a desktop LAN based app and then later build a web application which the user can interact that ultimately talks to a single local database ? or in other words windows desktop app and a web app connecting to a single local database...

Answer (score 0):

## Database Server

Install a database server such as Postgres or H2 Database.

A database server acts as a black box, dutifully storing data while waiting for incoming connections from clients. Those clients can be administrative apps for defining the data tables and verifying their data contents, as pgAdmin. Or the client might be a custom app you wrote with a tool such as Xojo, with each user running an instance of that app on their particular PC, all those instances each making their connection to the database server. Or the client to the database server might be a web app server such as a Java Servlets container like Apache Tomcat or Eclipse Jetty on Java SE running a web app you built using the Vaadin framework.

All of these types of database clients (DB admin app, custom desktop app, and web app server) can all be hitting your database server at the same time.